# Naturality of the lie bracket.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-derivative

I heard the term natural transformation for functors. Does the naturality of the lie bracket has something to do with that?
**Naturality of the lie bracket** : $F_*[V_1,V_2]=[F_*V_1,F_*V_2]$ where the star denotes the pushforward and $V_1$, $V_2$ are vector fields.

Comment: See problem $11-18$ in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds (second edition) for the definition of natural transformations in category theory. The Lie bracket is an example of a natural transformation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, these ideas can be expressed in the language of category theory.
For instance, the fact that the star is a subscript (instead of a superscript) on $F_*$ indicates that there is a *covariant functor* (instead of a *contravariant functor*) behind the scenes. To be precise, the naturality you seek involves the category **Diff** with smooth manifolds as *objects* and diffeomorphisms as *morphisms*, as well as the category **Vect**$_\mathbf{R}$ with real vector spaces as objects and linear maps as morphisms.

In this language, $\mathfrak{X}$ is a *functor* from **Diff** to **Vect**$_\mathbf{R}$ sending diffeomorphisms $F\colon M\to N$ of smooth manifolds to linear maps $F_*\colon\mathfrak{X}(M)\to\mathfrak{X}(N)$, where $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ denotes the space of smooth vector fields on $M$. That is, $\mathfrak{X}\colon F\mapsto F_*$.

Similarly, we may define a functor $\mathfrak{X}\times\mathfrak{X}$ from **Diff** to **Vect**$_\mathbf{R}$ by sending $F$ to $F_*\times F_*$, where
$(F_*\times F_*)\colon\mathfrak{X}(M)\times\mathfrak{X}(M)\to\mathfrak{X}(N)\times\mathfrak{X}(N)$ is defined as one may expect — namely by sending $(X,Y)$ to $(F_*X,F_*Y)$.

The Lie bracket $[\cdot,\cdot]\colon\mathfrak{X}\times\mathfrak{X}\to\mathfrak{X}$ is then a *natural transformation* from the functor $\mathfrak{X}\times\mathfrak{X}$ to the functor $\mathfrak{X}$, as the identity $F_*[X,Y]=[F_*X,F_*Y]$ is precisely the statement that the *diagram*

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}\mathfrak{X}(M)\times \mathfrak{X}(M)     @>F_*\times F_*>>  \mathfrak{X}(N)\times \mathfrak{X}(N)\\@VV[\cdot,\cdot]V        @VV[\cdot,\cdot]V\\\mathfrak{X}(M)     @>F_*>>  \mathfrak{X}(N)\end{CD}$$

*commutes*.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

One possible view which would make the use of the term "natural" here refer to natural transformation is to think of the space of vector fields as a sheaf of Lie-algebras. Thinking of a sheaf as a functor and viewing the pushforward associated to a smooth map on the base manifolds as a natural transformation between these functors may are may not serve as a satisfying interpretation, depending on your tastes.